# problem with running tzscan: Camlp4: Uncaught exception: DynLoader.Error

Tags: tzscan

```
Error:
[763.1] 'camlp4o' '-I' '/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/ocaml' 
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/ocaml/unix.cma' '-I' 
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/ocaml' 
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/ocaml/str.cma' 
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/ocaml/bigarray.cma' '-I' 
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/calendar' 
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/calendar/calendarLib.cma' '-I' 
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/re' 
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/re/re.cma' 
'-I' '/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/csv' 
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/csv/csv.cma' '-I' 
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/sexplib' '-I' 
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/sexplib/0' '-I' 
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/sexplib/unix' 
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/sexplib0/sexplib0.cma' 
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/parsexp/parsexp.cma' 
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/sexplib/sexplib.cma' 
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/sexplib/unix/sexplib_unix.cma' '-I' 
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/cstruct' 
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/cstruct/cstruct.cma' '-I' 
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/hex' 
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/hex/hex.cma' '-I' 
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/pgocaml' 
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/pgocaml/pgocaml.cma' '-I' 
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/pgocaml'
'/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/pgocaml/pa_pgsql.cma' './src/db/alias.mli'

Camlp4: Uncaught exception: DynLoader.Error 
("/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/cstruct/cstruct.cma", "error while linking /home/ubuntu/.opam/4.07.1/lib/cstruct/cstruct.cma.\nReference to undefined global `Bigarray_compat'")
```

Comment: hi, welcome to TSE! could you please add more description about your issue, what you did to get this error etc.. Giving context help people to give you an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original TzScan OS available at https://gitlab.com/tzscan/tzscan does not compile easily for the moment unfortunately.  You could ask help there.

Otherwise, you can also try an installer script of TzScan OS, available at https://gitlab.com/tezos-southeast-asia/tzscaninstaller . Note that this uses a fork of TzScan OS, available at https://gitlab.com/tezos-southeast-asia/tzscan .  If you have any problem of the installer you can ask help the issue page of tzscaninstaller.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me a lot.